# Yoga for obese male

Tags: yoga

Is there a type of yoga that would be do able for an obese male with the limitations of obesity and gender (if there are) considered?

Comment: What's your weight, height and age btw? Are there specific concerns that you have about just regular yoga classes?

Comment: Its a general question more in that obese people I would imagine would have issues with the range of motion required

Comment: [Seems like some manage fine.](http://foodcourtlunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/flexible_fat_guy.jpg)

Comment: A good yoga teacher at a beginner's or all-levels class, no matter what style of yoga, should be able to give variations that everyone can do. Yoga is a balance between listening to your body and obeying its limitations, while simultaneously pushing yourself a little more than you think you can go. The best advice is to get a yoga teacher who can give you some individual attention and help you with what YOUR body tells you.

Comment: The [Shavasana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savasana) is great ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say you could start with some balance poses to help your body adjust to supporting your body weight while in different positions. You could also try Hatha yoga which is generally a slower paced yoga which can help you to adjust to the poses and get comfortable with them before moving on to faster paced yoga routines like power yoga, vinyasa or ashtanga. But only do what your comfortable with, nothing wrong with going slow.

Answer (score 2):

Its not so much about the style, but a lot of classes have a lot of fit young women, so you need to find one where you "fit in", preferably a dedicated beginners class.
(If the teacher is old female, the students are more likely to be old)

An Ingyear teacher will usually adapt the program well to your level.

I will recommend against Astanga (for unfit people), as they have this one fixed program, and also put a lot of strain on parts of the body.

I don't generally recommend Bikram, but I think its OK for unfit.

Comment: why don't you recommend Bikram?